# Deeply merge objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using `$mergeObjects` In an aggregation pipeline, but it only merge the object at first level.

I want to achieve a deeply merge (at any level) without knowing what properties could it be in each object.

For example, if I have these 2 objects:

```
{
    a:1,
    b: {
        c:1
        d:1
    },
    g: [1,2]
}
{
    b:{
        c:2,
        e:2
    },
    f:2,
    g:[3,4]
}
```

The final result should be like this:

```
{
    a:1,
    b:{
        c:2,
        d:1,
        e:2
    },
    f:2,
    g: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Note that could be more nested levels inside any objects, and also it could be more than 2 objects to merge.

Could this be done dynamically?

Comment: I dont think this can be done with aggregate operators for unknown fileds and any random depth.Maybe with some custom javascript [`$accumulator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/) , but having a schema with unknown fields and unknown depth, doesnt look good idea i think.

Comment: I could this with a recursive function in JS, but I wonder if there is something that can be done directly in MongoDB.